# Location of Application.php in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, cpanel, include-path, internal-server-error

I'm trying to setup the following application up on my server which relies on Framework. https://github.com/medialab/ANTA

The application fails because it can't find application.php. I have downloaded the Zend framework and tried quite a lot of different things, but none have so far worked. What puzzels me the most is that there is no application.php file in the Zend framework? Am i using a wrong version or just missing the point of Zend?

Hope somebody has the solution... Zend is still very new for to me :)

```
Warning: require_once(/home/***/public_html/mapping/ANTA/library/Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/***/public_html/mapping/ANTA/public/index.php on line 22 Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/***/public_html/mapping/ANTA/library/Zend/Application.php' (include_path='/home/***/public_html/mapping/ANTA/library:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/***/public_html/mapping/ANTA/public/index.php on line 22
```

Comment: Make sure you're using the right version of ZF and also look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559275/zend-failed-opening-zend-application-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your application needs ZF1, but you've downloaded ZF2 (the current version).

You can still download ZF1 from the Zend site: http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest#ZF1